# Anet A8 moves down into piece, destroying it, just before the printer is set to finish

Tags: troubleshooting, anet-a8, z-axis

I hope someone can help me figure out what's going on with my printer. I have been printing a couple of pieces and it's been printing perfectly. But for some reason every now and then, the printer moves down into the piece just before it finishes printing (after the final top layer) and completely wrecks the piece. I have no idea why this is doing it, and nothing I haven't changed the G-code since. to prove this, I printed an old model that I had on my computer, and it still managed to do it. Please help I have no idea why it's doing this.

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! With "before finishes" you mean that there are a few layers to go, or after the last layer?

Comment: I mean on the very last layer. To confirm, I just watched it finish the last layer and begin to move downward into the piece and melt it. I have no idea why it's doing this

Comment: Sometimes if the carriage is heavy, and the steppers are depowered, the carriage drops, if the nozzle is still hot, then it will dig in the print. The alternative is that you command the printer to dig into the print. Please share the last 30 lines or so of the G-code file you print and possibly the end G-code.

Comment: Look into question: [3D printer ends print by sinking in to it and getting stuck](/q/6860), this may answer your question?